# the below code the scanf is not reading my characters in the while loop?

Tags: c

my code is not working as i expected.if s the number words to be printed.then s-1 will be the number of spaces between them.in the while loop scanf reads the characters one bye one if it encounters a space it increments k.when k equals s-1 the break statement is executed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
int i,j,k=0,s;
char a[100];
scanf("%d",&s);
i=0;
while(1)
{

    scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    i++;
    if(a[i]==' ')
    k++;

    if(k==(s-1))
   break;
  }
   puts(a);
  }
```

Comment: another problem is that the `puts` function expects a null-terminated string, but you have not built such a string in `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get errors while running loops, try to run them manually on paper for two or three iterations which will make us understand how our code flow is happening in a loop.

In your code, when you run the loop for first time, you are taking the character into `a[0]`, incrementing value of i and which now makes the value of `i` as `1`, now you are comparing the value of `a[1]` to `' '` which is a garbage. correct it to the following code,

```
scanf("%c",&a[i]);    
//i++;    
if(a[i++]==' ')    
   k++;
```

you are declaring `int main(void)` and not returning any value. include a `return 0;` statement at the end along with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c",&a[i]);
i++;
if(a[i]==' ')
    k++;
```

When you compare `a[i]` against `' '`, it's not assigned yet. This leads you to undefined behavior.

Comment: but scanf comes before the comparison if(a[i]==' '); so a[i] will be assigned a value entered by the us.

Comment: @nani But the `i++` in between already updated the value of `i`.